# TypeScript Declaration File not working for NPM Module

Tags: typescript, npm, declaration

I've been creating a package for NPM. (It's a JSON wrapped database kinda thing), it's a fun little project. I'd like to include a declaration for the functions (like `<QDb>.Connect();`), but can't get the hang of adding it. Directory structure:

```
node_modules
QDatabase
    Docs
        QDb.d.ts
    Utils
package-lock.json
package.json
QDb.js
```

In the declaration file, I have basic stuff like `export function Connect(Path: String, Callback?: function): void | Error;`. On the top of the file, I added `import {Connect} from "../../QDb.js";` (with all the other functions, I'm just using Connect for example here).

When I link the package to my home folder, then link it in a test project; It does not show any declaration for the function, only the basic JavaScript but not the `@description`, `@param`, `@emits`, `@returns`, and such.

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong? Help is much appreciated.

~Q

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a `"types": "./QDatabase/Docs/QDb.d.ts"` in your package.json. More infos on the [TypeScript's docs on publishing packages](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I already figured it out, but nevertheless, thank you anyways.